# MacOS - clean up python installs

Tags: python, macos, zsh

I would like to learn python and found a couple of tutorials and guides on how to install python on macOS (13.0.1) and I've managed to make a big mess.

I've installed a version from python.org as well as from brew. So, I cleaned up my system a little bit as follows:

This was the initial output of `florian@Mac ~ % ls -l /usr/bin/python*`

```
-rwxr-xr-x  76 root  wheel  167136 Oct 28 10:43 /usr/bin/python3
```

But  `which python` got me this : `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10`

So, I've found this: [link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/284824/remove-and-reinstall-python-on-mac-can-i-trust-these-old-references)

And I deleted my Python.Framework directory.

I reinstalled python via brew via `brew reinstall python@3.10`

And I got the following

```
Python has been installed as
  /opt/homebrew/bin/python3

Unversioned symlinks `python`, `python-config`, `pip` etc. pointing to
`python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3` etc., respectively, have been installed into
  /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.10/libexec/bin

You can install Python packages with
  pip3 install <package>
They will install into the site-package directory
  /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages
```

The test `florian@Mac ~ % which python3` shows me now: `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3`

But my .zprofile is still showing this:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.10
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

And also the commands `pip`,`python` are not know in the terminal.

My 2 questions are:

1. Do I need to add alias for pip and python to use these instead of `pip3p` and `python3`
2. For updating the PATH, would it be `PATH="/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/bin:${PATH}"`?

Comment: This is a common situation for Python newcomers, and even not-so-newcomers :) https://xkcd.com/1987/ More helpfully, just update the `zprofile` (or just put it in `.zshrc`) with the new Python path, then restart your shell, and you should have your Homebrew-installed Python binaries available